# Using Wine and py2exe to create windows application out of a Python project

Tags: python, windows, linux, py2exe, wine

I recently built an application, for a client, which has several python files. I use ubuntu, and now that I am finished, I would like to give this to the client in a way that would make it easy for her to use in windows.

I have looked into py2exe with wine, as well as cx_freeze and some other stuff, but cannot find a straightforward tutorial or useful documentation for turning many python files in ubuntu into an easy-to-use windows application or executable or anything really.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not invest in a copy of windows, and some virtualisation software, and just do the operation in windows?

Comment: I could do that, but I'm far from wealthy and figured there'd be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Consider it a cost of doing business; in any case, it is likely to be the most simple way. There may well be more complex but cheaper methods, though.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/26340-linux-wine-py2exe) appears to have a solution, as the asker didn't reply:

1. Install WINE.
2. Use WINE to install Python 2.3.
3. Use WINE to install py2exe.
4. Make a setup.py file for py2exe to compile your script:

> ```
> from distutils.core import setup
> import py2exe
>
> setup(name="vervang",
>   scripts=["vervang.py"],
> )
> ```

- Run `wine python.exe setup.py py2exe`

[This page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Py2Exe) says the resulting binaries might not be valid Win32 executables, though.

Answer (score 1):

py2exe will not work on linux. Try [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) it is a pure python implementation that will work on linux, mac and windows.

Comment: Just as a little information - the [FAQ](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/FAQ) states that you would still have to use wine with pyinstaller.

Comment: I have a machine for linux and a machine for windows so i never knew that. Thanks for the tip.